# Combine two Morris charts in one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, morris.js

I am trying to combine two Morris charts, which is bar chart and line chart in the same element (frame),but when I trying to apply two morris charts in one element, my charts aren't display correctly.
Here you go, the code I'm using:

```
var month_data = [
    {"period": '2010', "licensed": 100, "sorned": 60},
    {"period": '2011', "licensed": 75, "sorned": 29},
    {"period": '2012', "licensed": 50, "sorned": 18},
    {"period": '2013', "licensed": 75, "sorned": 61},
    {"period": '2014', "licensed": 50, "sorned": 67},
    {"period": '2015', "licensed": 75, "sorned": 7},
    {"period": '2016', "licensed": 100, "sorned": 60}
];
Morris.Line({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: month_data,
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['licensed', 'sorned'],
    zkeys: 3,
    labels: ['Licensed', 'SORN'],
    smooth: false
});

Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: [
        { y: '2010', a: 100, b: 90 },
        { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2012', a: 50,  b: 40 },
        { y: '2013', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2014', a: 50,  b: 40 },
        { y: '2015', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2016', a: 100, b: 90 }
    ],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
    zkeys: 0,
    labels: ['Block A', 'Block B']
});
```

and as result of this code, I am getting this:
[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iypDO.png)

Comment: You want the Morris Bar and Morris Line to be superposed?

Comment: Any updates on this? I am also having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sort of hack for this which seems to work pretty nicely.

Just define the style of the container element to display block and the child svg elements should be display absolute;

```
#bar-example{
    height:400px;
    width:800px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:relative;
}
#bar-example svg{
    position:absolute!important;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Then hide the x Axis labels and hover legend for one of the charts.

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: month_data,
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['licensed', 'sorned'],
    zkeys: 3,
    labels: ['Licensed', 'SORN'],
    smooth: false,
    xLabelFormat: function(){
      return '';
    },
    hideHover: 'always'
});
```

https://codepen.io/eyeballface/pen/XWmOZpQ